# Is there any maven plugin for compress html only?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am running yuicompressor-maven-plugin plugins for compressing js files, but have to minify HTML files also. Project running on AngularJS 
Is there any specific plugin by putting in POM.xml I can achieve. Location of the output file should be at the same place where the source file is available.

I have tried htmlcompressor-maven-plugin.
https://javalibs.com/plugin/com.tunyk.mvn.plugins.htmlcompressor/htmlcompressor-maven-plugin

But its comressing html to single js file like bundle that's not required, and required specific source folder requirement to use this like `src/main/resources`

Comment: And did the htmlcompressor plugin did the job? Or did you hade issues getting this plugin to run? Or was it not sufficient? What requirements do you have, that the plugin does not fulfill?

Comment: @Korashen it's not compressing as expected like take a file from source folders and after minify put at the same folder with the same file name.